# How do I get elements out of a AWS DynamoDB for a simple web app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, amazon-dynamodb, frontend, aws-api-gateway

I am part of a student group that is trying out AWS and trying to build a VERY small basic severless application. We did one of the AWS
tutorials ( https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-web-app-s3-lambda-api-gateway-dynamodb/?nc1=h_ls ).

So now we have this web app where we can save names in a DynamoDB. But how can we access the DynamoDB with Lamda/ Frontend (JS) to get elements out of it and display the information? All these services with API Gateway, DynamoDB and Lamda and how they work together is quite confusing. We can't figure out how to use a simple REST API to get elements out of the Database.

Can anyone help us out? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: The tutorial you linked explains everything, step by step.  Did you go through it?

Comment: Yes, we did go through it. It also works perfectly. But it only explains how to put sth. into the Database but not how to get sth. out.

Comment: Check out the tutorial at serverless-stack.com, it's an extremely comprehensive guide to building a serverless web app with the technologies you're working with.  They go step-by-step through the entire process, which includes performing database operations in Lambda.  https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/what-does-this-guide-cover.html

Comment: Alright thanks, we will check out some of the tutorials. We didn't know that website :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using one of the strongly typed AWS APIs to build an application that uses Amazon DynamoDB. There is a Spring based example that builds an application that performs CRUD operations on data located in an Amazon DynamoDB table. This example uses the Enhanced Client that perform data mapping between Java classes and a table.

[Map items in DynamoDB tables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/examples-dynamodb-enhanced.html)

Link to the AWS tutorial that uses the Java API V2 is:

[Creating the DynamoDB web application item tracker](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/examples-dynamodb-enhanced.html)

Likewise, here is a JavaScript example that uses Amazon DynamoDB:

[Build an app to submit data to DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/cross-service-example-submitting-data.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the boto3 libraries, they are fairly well documented.

In this case, you probably want to look into the [get_item](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.get_item) method of the dynamo client.